# problem handling promise in useState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, async-await, promise

After selecting two values ​​from a list, I must make a call to an api that returns a Json with the information

In this way I call the api that responds with the JSON

```
export default class ProductsService {
   
   async getProducts(channel, category){
       const aux = await axios.post('https://appshop.dapducasse.cl/ducasse-api/api/Qrs?channel='+encodeURIComponent(channel)+'&category='+encodeURIComponent(category)).then(data =>data.data).catch(e => [])
      
       return aux
   } 
}
```

In this way I make the call from the react component

```
  const chanelService = new ChanelService();
   const categoryService = new CategoryService();
   const productsService = new ProductsService();

   

   useEffect(() => {
       chanelService.getChanels().then(data => setChanels(data))
       categoryService.getCategories().then(data => setCateries(data))
   }, []);

   const testChargue = async ( ) =>{
       console.log(selectedChannel)
       console.log(selectedCategory)
       const a = await productsService.getProducts(selectedChannel, selectedCategory).then(data => setProducts(data));
       console.log(products)

   }
```

When I press the button, the function should be executed where the call is made with the Channel and the selected product.

I don't get the json on the first click of the button, but on the second, I think this happens because the execution ends before setProducts defines the state of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `products` and `setProducts` refer to local state in your component?

In this case `products` in the last line will always be the "old" value inside your handler function, because `setProducts` will not update that variable. The variable will only changed when the component will been re-rendered, but not during the execution of your handler function. I think that's why you see the value when pressing the button twice. On the second click the component has been re-rendered, so the value also in your handler function has been updated.

More on "stale" state in the react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function